# \listoffigures and \listoftables don't appear in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

My bibliography link appears in the table of contents, but the figures and tables lists don't. Here is how I get them:

```
% ustawienie bibliografii
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{acm-i}
\bibliography{bib_database} 
\clearpage

\listoftables
\clearpage

\listoffigures
```

The bibliography is then seen in the TOC as literature:

[image]

But no sight of figures and tables. I will also have to use source code listing and I wonder if that will show up. Is there a way to force figures and tables to enter the TOC? I would appreciate all help.
I am using the `mwart` document class.

Here is my config:

```
%% Clear sans, courier

% Klasa:
\documentclass[12pt]{mwart}

% Kodowanie:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Czcionki:
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Clear Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{polski}

% Geometria i style
%\usepackage{showframe} % debug
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,twoside=true,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,inner=35mm,outer=20mm}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{afterpage}

% Grafika
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

% kody
\usepackage{listings}

% matma
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

% theoremy
\usepackage{amsthm}

% Stopnie
\usepackage{gensymb}

% Numerowanie obiektow wedlug rozdzialow
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% Linki
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyref}

% Listy
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=3ex, Style*=-- ,
Style2*=$\bullet$ ,Style3*=$\circ$ ,Style4*=\tiny$\blacksquare$ )

% Zmienne srodowiskowe:
\newcommand{\tocLessLeft}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessLeftNorm}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\normalsize \flushleft{#1}}} \vspace{0mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\tocLessCenter}[1]{\textsc{\textbf{\large \centerline{#1}}} \vspace{3mm} \\ \indent }
\newcommand{\insertImg}[3]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=50mm]{#1}
    \caption{#2} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#3}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}
\newcommand{\insertImgSetSize}[4]{%
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=#2mm]{#1}
    \caption{#3} \flushleft{Źródło: Na podstawie \cite{#4}}
    \label{#1}
\end{figure}
}

% Indeksowanie w pdfie wyjsciowym
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Naprawienie referencji do figur
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{figure.section.thesection.\thefigure}

% START:
\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: I am using mwart, I edited the question.

Comment: Have a look into the toc and \addcontentsline{toc}{0 or 1}{name of the section}. Something like this should work.

Comment: But should I look into the `mwart` classdocument you mean?

Comment: It might be, but I need to change it somehow.

Comment: I made a test file and I see both “Spis tablic” and “Spis rysunków” in the “Spis treści”. A minimal example is needed.

Comment: Yes this is the problem, When I created the minimal example just now, I see them as well. I am wondering what could kill it in my document.

Comment: @ŁukaszPrzeniosło Divide and conquer; but maybe showing a list of the packages you're loading could suffice.

Comment: @egreg I added the code

Comment: Sorry, but I still get the lists in the table of contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40435/discussion-between-lukasz-przenioslo-and-egreg).

Comment: The memoir class includes the tables and figures lists in the ToC. Perhaps you could look at the code to see how it is done.

Comment: @PeterWilson It's your fault! `;-)` The `tocloft` package should not change the code for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` by default. In any case, the name of the `titles` option is not well chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the package `tocloft` that you didn't mention in your question (but provided it in chat).

If called without options, the package seizes the initiative and *changes* the code for `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`. Call it with the `titles` option:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
```

I know, the option name is misleading (but the standard behavior is even worse).

[image]